# Vertical align text with icon

Tags: html, css

I've a text as below is not aligning as vertical in the middle of icon.

How do I solve this, please?

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/ali.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/ali.png)

CSS:

```
#text{ color:#48c4d2; font-size:15px; font-family:opensansitalic;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="blurb"><button class="blue_small" id="blue_small"></button> Available in video.</div>
```

UPDATE:

This should explain it.

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/ali2.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/ali2.png)

Comment: can you explain your problem a bit more detailled. Do you want a button with a text vertically centered or a button with a text next to it centered to it vertically? btw your css has no link to the html part

Comment: UPDATE: screen grab with what I'm trying to do, in red line across. I've used photoshop to move text down to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a **CSS background image** and use `padding-left:` to move the text over, and use `background-position:` to adjust the position of the image. And if it's a link, use an A-tag, not a button.

```
<a href="..." class="videoBlurb">Available in video.</a>
```

No need to nest tags as you're doing.

Something like:

```
.videoBlurb {
    display:block;
    background-image:url(....);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0px 0px;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-top:20px;
    color:#48c4d2;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:opensansitalic;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Diodeus makes a good point and definitely has the most useful answer, but for the sake of curiosity without changing your markup - it should actually be this simple:

```
​button {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Of course, be more specific with the selector. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/beV7j/2

Comment: I guess this is not right, because the text is not in the button. The text would be centered to it by default without changing anything. See http://jsfiddle.net/GeKG9/

Comment: The fact that the button has no text is not an accident, but not good practice. At the very least, one should put text in it and use an "image replacement" technique like `text-indent:-999px` to hide the text if necessary. Diodeus has the all around best practice in his answer, and this does not look like it should be a `button` in the first place. I do see your point though @pfried

Comment: Thanks Wesley. Yours worked as well. It is better to use css in good practice.